# Understanding Java super() constructor

Tags: java, constructor, super

I'm trying to understand Java `super()` constructor. Let's take a look in the following class:

```
class Point {
    private int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point() {
        this(0, 0);
    }
}
```

This class will compile. If we create a new `Point` object say `Point a = new Point();` The constructor with no parameters will be called: `Point()`.

Correct me if I'm wrong, before doing `this(0,0)`, the `Class` constructor will be called and only then `Point(0,0)` will be called.
If this is true, is it correct to say that `super()` is being called by default?

Now let's look at the same code with a small change:

```
class Point {

        private int x, y;

        public Point(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public Point() {
            super();   // this is the change.
            this(0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Now, the code won't compile because `this(0,0)` is not in the first line of the constructor. This is where I get confused. Why the code won't compile? Doesn't `super()` is being called anyway? (The Class constructor as described above).

Comment: Point is not a subclass. Imagine if we had a subclass PrettyPoint, then PrettyPoint() { super(0,0); } would call Point(int x, int y) from above.

Comment: This will help you to understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381244/why-cant-this-and-super-both-be-used-together-in-a-constructor

Comment: @ZeldaZach Everything is a subclass of `Object`.

Comment: @Rom What is the compiler error in the second version of your code?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168345/why-do-this-and-super-have-to-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `this()` **or** `super()` but not both from the same constructor. When you call `this()`, `super()` is called automatically from the **other** constructor (the one that you call with `this()`).

Comment: And therefore I have 2x calls for super(). Thank you.

Comment: @Rom If the code could compile, that would be one of the results, yes.

Answer (score 5):

`this(0, 0);` will call, constructor of the same class and `super()` will call super/parent class of `Point` class.

> Now, the code won't compile because this(0,0) is not in the first line
>   of the constructor. This is where I get confused. Why the code won't
>   compile? Doesn't super() is being called anyway?

`super()` must be the first line of the constructor and also `this()` must be the first line in the constructor. So both cannot be in the first line(not possible), that means, we cannot add both in a constructor.

As a explonation about your code:

`this(0, 0);` will call to the constructor that takes two parameters(in `Point` class) and that two parameter constructor will call to the `super()` implicitly(because you didnt call it explicitly).

Answer (score 4):

Put super() in your first constructor, it should work.

```html
class Point {

        private int x, y;

        public Point(int x, int y) {
            super();   // this is the change.
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public Point() {
            
            this(0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By calling `this(...)` you are forced to call the super constructor (if present) in the constructor you're calling there.

Calling `this(...)` or `super(...)` is always the first method you're calling in a constructor.

**EDIT**

```
class Point {
    private int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        super(...); //would work here
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point() {
        this(0, 0); //but this(...) must be first in a constructor if you want to call another constructor
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly my point. If i'm forced to call the super constructor, what difference does it make if I call it explicitly by super() and then call this(..)?

Comment: You are not allowed to call super/this as a second method. If you want to call a super constructor, you need to do it in the constructor you're calling.

Answer (score 1):

A constructor can call the constructor of a super class using the `super()` method call. Only constraint is that it should be the first statement.

```
public Animal() { 
    super();
    this.name = "Default Name"; 
}
```

**Will this code Compile?**

```
public Animal() {
    this.name = "Default Name"; 
    super();
}
```

Answer is **NO**. `super()` should be always called on the first line of the constructor.